# How do I run npm install and such commands for a JS project on a local Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I run a `npm install` command in the console?

I downloaded a project on Github and uploaded it on my Node.js (localhost) server. Script is not running at all. Creator says I have to run these commands, I do not know how to do it. I type them in the console and nothing happens. When I enter on the website I see a blank page and the JS is not loading. How do I run all these for the script to work ?

```
# install dependencies

npm install



# serve with hot reload at localhost:8080

npm run dev



# build for production with minification

npm run build



# run unit tests

npm run unit



# run e2e tests

npm run e2e



# run all tests

npm test
```

Comment: You should run first 2 commands in the directory of file you've downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize node first to create a package.json so

```
`npm install`
```

knows what to install.

Try running `npm init` before `npm install`

Comment: Brother hi. I tried it and the package.json exists alredy from the creator of the project but when I type npm install this is what happens, errors ...

Comment: Some packages compile and you are getting an error in the process. Is your Node version the recommended one?

Comment: Project is on C:\Users\Warpaint\WebApplication

Comment: Brother hi I tried and it stil ldeosn`t work. Creator of script said this : 
 For detailed explanation on how things work, checkout the guide and docs for vue-loader. 

These are the errors I get on first picture when writing npm install
2nd pic is error when I type npm run dev
The project is in C:\Users\Warpaint\WebApplication
I ran all commands before I typed at the end 
npm install http-server -g 
and before 
http-server C:\Users\Warpaint\WebApplication
still the website is blank ... probably cause the scripts aren`t running
Should I make the package.json again ?

Comment: All of those error messages are complaining about `node-sass`. See what happens if you remove it from package.json & `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install npm first: https://www.npmjs.com/